# how to detect/disable MouseLeftButtonDown event on listbox's vertical SCROLLbar in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, listbox, scrollbar

I have attached `MouseLeftButtonDown` event to silverlight listbox and in this event i do something. But when I click on vertical scrollbar, this event also gets fired. I don't want to execute the code in that event handler when click is on scrollbar. Is there any property of ListBox which enables us to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

but this condition always return true wherever we click in listbox but if you click on scrollbar it will gives false

you can check sender's type using below code

```
if (sender.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Controls.ListBox))
```

if it is list box then do your logic else not.

My Xaml code is

```
 <ListBox Name="lstbx" MouseLeftButtonDown="ListBox_MouseLeftButtonDown" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"></ListBox>
```

and my Xaml.cs code is

```
 public void ListBox_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: but this condition always returns true wherever we click in listbox

Comment: have you tried this at your end, if so can you paste the code here plz

Comment: I have tried but while clicking on Scrollbar of Listbox MouseLeftButtonDown is not being fired. it is only fired when i click on listbox.